# How to get the time not from the device but from the internet?

Tags: datetime, flutter

I have a problem that If a person clock is not set correctly the app will take this time rather than the correct one that's why I wanted to take the time now form the internet. any idea ?

Note: I have used DateTime.now() and it provide back the mobile time not the real time

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/true_time

Comment: it returns null time I have used their example and it didnot work

Comment: i will suggest you use a restful API